# Display Lookup fields in lwc component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, child-to-parent, lookup-field

I wrote my lwc code in vscode.

Then I wrote in apex class a method that returns list<MyCustomObject__c> =[Select ...];

I used child-to-parent relationship so I used **Child__r**(*Lookup(child) in Parent__c Object*) and **Parent__c** in my query to extract child's name of a particular parent.

My Apex Code is:

```
public with sharing class ApplicantsController {     
        @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static List<Application__c> getApplicantsList() {
           
           return [SELECT Child__r.First_Name__c,Child__r.Middle_Name__c,Child__r.Last_Name__c,Total_Nb_Children__c
                                          FROM Parent__c 
                                          WHERE Parent_id_code='a0A7Q000001PZcuUAG'];
        
        }
}
```

***NB:*** When I run the query in **developer console** I got results.
Hence my query is correct
and when I refresh the page in **Salesfoce** I only got result of # of Children the other column are empty

**In my Javascript code I used :**

const columns = [
{ label: 'First Name', fieldName: 'Child__r.First_Name__c' },

```
{ label: 'Middle Name', fieldName: 'Child__r.Middle_Name__c' },

{ label: 'Last Name', fieldName: 'Child__r.Last_Name__c' },

{ label: '# of children', fieldName: 'Total_Nb_Children__c' },      *----ONLY THIS is SHOWN In MY SALESFORCE TABLE -----*
```

];

What should I change in order to show the lookup fields?

Comment: Hope this helps: https://www.infallibletechie.com/2021/03/how-to-display-parent-field-value-in.html

Comment: tempRecords = tempRecords.map( row => {
                return { …row, Name: row.Product2.Name, Family: row.Product2.Family };
            })     ---------------in the "...row " in what should I replace it ? @CloundConnect

Comment: I am working with Custom Objects @RubenDG

Comment: That answer is valid for both custom and standard objects. Standard lightning-datatable doesn't support relationship field, you have to flatten them.